# AutoSizeTextType uniform doesn`t work for custom text view in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android

I want to automatically scale font size depending on contents in Xamarin.Android app in custom class. Scaling works for TextView. But when I use `NoobTextView` scaling does not work.

[image: Custom TextView]
[image: Scales properly]
[image: Does not scale]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original TextView, the autosize attributes refer to the android: namespace.  And in it, auto-size only works on the latest versions of the droid.  Attributes from app: are only picked up by appcompat versions.  Judging by the fact that now it works in this form - I have an AppCompat or Material theme installed, in which, during inflate, an AppCompatTextView or MaterialTextView is created instead of a TextView.  Accordingly, no substitution occurs for custom TextViews.  The solution is to inherit from AppCompatTextView.